# Compact Subsets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I drastically need help with these questions. I have been working on this last problem for hours and do not even know where to start or what I am doing. The questions are:

a) Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $p \in \mathbb{R} \setminus K.$ Prove that there exist points $a, b \in K$ such that $|a - p| =$ inf$\{|x - p| : x \in K\}$ and $|b - p| =$ sup$\{|x - p| : x \in K\}.$

b) Are either of the above true if $K$ is only closed?

Comment: Can you use the fact that any continuous function on a compact set achieves its minimum and maximum? Or is that not yet covered?

Comment: For closed sets, take $(x,1/x)  , x>0 $ and the x-axis in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: You can also use the equivalence (in metric spaces) with sequential compactness.

Comment: But I think for $\mathbb R^1$ it is also true for $K$ closed only, but not for $\mathbb R^k ; k>1$

Answer (score 2):

There is a sequence $x_n \in K$ such that $|x_n - p| \to\ \mathrm{inf}  \{|x - p| : x \in K \}$.

As $K$ is compact, every Cauchy sequence in $K$ converges within $K$. So $x_n$ converges to some $x$.

Similarly for the supremum.

It does not work for closed sets, because for example the supremum can be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the equivalence of compactness and sequential compactness for metric spaces: let $m:=inf |x-p|: x \in K$ . Then there is a sequence {$x_k$} of elements in K that converge to $m$. By sequential compactness of $K$, the limit $x$ of the sequence {$x_k$} is in $K$. By continuity of $d(x,p)$, you are done.

If $K$ is only closed but not compact, that implies, by Heine-Borel, that $K$ is closed and unbounded. But then you have, e.g., for $K:= \mathbb R-0, d(0,K)=0 $.